# create Directory and if exist then rename it

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am developing application in which i want that if user create folder and if it is already present then folder should automatically renamed by appending number to folder name

suppose server has folder with name Time now if user again creates folder than it new folder will be Time1 again user creates folder with same name(Time or Time1) than new Folder should be created with Time2 and so on... This is what i have done so far but recursion always return wrong value.

```
 public string checkIfExist(String path, String ProgramName, int itteration,out string strFolderName)
    {
        String uploadPath = "";
        strFolderName = "";
        String Mappath =HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
        if (Directory.Exists(Mappath))
        {
            String Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath((path + "" + ProgramName.Replace(" ", "_")));
            // uploadPath += ++itteration ;
            if (Directory.Exists(Path))
            {
                ProgramName += ++itteration;
                strFolderName = ProgramName;
                uploadPath = checkIfExist(path, ProgramName, itteration,out strFolderName);

            }
        }

        return ProgramName;
    }
```

Comment: i have updated my Question and put the code i have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could adapt this, to your need. I wrote it on the fly based on a piece of code I remember in an old file manager I was using in some projects, so please test it. **This doesn't include creation and so on, based on your example I'm sure you can add that yourself** but if you need help just comment below.

The idea is to pass the original name of the directory you want, and then return an appropriate new name if it exists, such as Test(1), Test(2), Test(n). Then once you get the name you need, you can create it directly.

```
protected string GetUniqueDirectoryName(string dirName)
{
  string newDirName = dirName;

  for (int i = 1; Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("PATH_HERE") + newDirName); i++)
  {
    newDirName = string.Format("{0}({1})", dirName, i);
  }

  return newDirName;
}
```

**Note**: You will need to include System.IO and probably use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath instead of Server.MapPath

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I really understand what you are trying to do, but I think using recursion here is a little overkill. Try something like this:

```
string dirName = "Time";
int counter = 0;

string dir = dirName;

while(Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    dir = String.Format("{0}{1}", dirName, (++counter).ToString());
}

Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
```